why is the for loop outputing the same number?
I'm trying to print random numbers created by the RollFor function using a for loop, but the numbers are always the same. I thought this might have something to do with variable scope, but so far I have not been able to get it to work.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int roll;

void RollFor(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    roll = (rand() % 6 + 1);
    printf("%d",roll);
}

int main(){
    
    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        RollFor();
    }
}

i tried creating a new seed inside the loop but it did not work.

Read the documentation for the functions you use. srand should be called only once in your program.

Depends on when you run it. If you managed to get some iterations in one second and some in the next you might get two different numbers. srand() — why call it only once?

This is ultimately a duplicate of the aforementioned: srand() — why call it only once? Move srand(time(NULL)); to the top of main and observe the results.

srand should be called only once, in your main, before the loop. You're getting the same value because the loop is short enough and the function fast enough that you're continually seeding the RNG with the same value.

You call time(NULL) in a loop, but the loop iterations were likely very quick. So consecutive calls to time(NULL) within the loop were likely returning the same value (the time difference may be less than a second), resulting in the same sequence of random numbers.
Try this, srand(time(NULL)) called only once in main:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int roll;

void RollFor(){
    roll = (rand() % 6 + 1); // range [1, 6]
    printf("%d",roll);
}

int main(){
    // call srand func only once
    srand(time(NULL));
    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        RollFor();
    }
}


Good answers are good because of their explanation, not necessarily because of their code.
